# Need Help Populating Table View With Structure Data

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to fill a table with data I have in a structure, elements_table, which contains an alpha literal element_name.  The following does not give a syntax error, but a warning of an incompatible pointer type.  I've never worked with a structure in a table view before.  Anyone have any ideas for me?  Thanks.

```
cell.textLabel.text = elements_table[0].element_name;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithCString:elements_table[0].element_name encoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding]` Since you said element_name is an alpha literal, I'm assuming its a string.

Comment: How do you know that "elements_table[0].element_name" is a string?

Comment: Well, originally I didn't. I incorrectly assumed element_name is a string. But Rick asked another question elsewhere on SO just moments ago and he gave the structure of elements_table. Also, elements_table.elements_name most certainly sounds like the name of the element (and a string) ALTHOUGH I could be wrong.

Comment: I tried the suggestion from @ravi.  I didn't get any errors or warnings, but the text that made it into my table was either Chinese or Japanese, I'm not sure which.

Comment: I took off the encoding part and it appears to have worked, in that I got the text I wanted in the table view.  However, I received a warning "stringWithCString is deprecated", but I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 0):

Check your data structure , `element_name` should be an object of `NSString` class.